# Clear unstaged files from my git status

Tags: git, github

I am just trying to setup a bitbucket repo with an existing app using `git remote add origin https://url` and it adds 1136 files..  How can I clear all of that?

Comment: Do you know ***why*** it's adding all those files? It's unusual. ***What are the exact commands that you're using***?

Comment: I have no idea.  That is the only command I used.

Comment: Is your Git remote already initialized before you run the `git remote add` command?

Comment: well I did a `git remote rm origin` before.  The git clean -df worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are untracked (i.e. have never been added to your Git repo before), then use the following:

```
git clean -df
```

Otherwise, use this:

```
git checkout -- .
```